# ipset not executing from crontab

Tags: bash, scripting, cron, iptables, ipset

I have this txt files that contains IPs, one per line of file, that I want to block using ipset.

I have this bash script that essentially reads from the plain txt file and constructs an array. Then it iterates the array elements and add each one to the ipset I have created for that purpose.

The problem is this: if I execute the script manually from the terminal, it works perfectly, but when I add the script to run periodically using crontab, the script runs but the IPs are not added to the ipset.

This is the relevant part of the script.

```
index=0
while true; do
  ipset -quiet -A myIpset $[arrayOfIPS[$index]}
  index=$[$index + 1]
  if [ "$index" -gt "$lastIndexOfArray" ];
  then break
  fi 
done
```

This works perfectly from terminal but not running from a crontab task.
why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell knows where to find executables (like `ipset`) by looking in your `PATH`, which is set by your environment. `cron` does not share the same environment. Adding this at the top of the crontab (or your script) should tell it where to find commands as you expect:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: that's it. Simply perfect!!!!!!!!!!!!!! THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer is different, but is there a reason you don't use the built-in commands?

such as this is crontab

```
@reboot /usr/sbin/ipset restore -f /ip/ipall.txt
```

and

```
ipset save -f /ip/ipall.txt
```